# JTabbedPane FocusTraversalPolicy

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabbedPane which has 4 Tabs. Each Tab has a JTable. I am trying to design a custom FocusTraversalPolicy for the JTabbedPane such that I can when I am focused on the last cell of the table, pressing tab takes me to the next tab. I have searched a lot but haven't found something specific that I can work with.

```
tabbedPane.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
tabbedPane.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
tabbedPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new MyPanelFocusTraversalPolicy(tabbedTables));
```

Following is my custom focus traversal policy.

```
    private class MyPanelFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy{
        private Vector<Component> order;
        public StateWithholdingPanelFocusTraversalPolicy(List<CopyWorkerSingleTablePanel> table){
            this.order = new Vector<Component>(table.size());
            this.order.addAll(table);
        }
        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            return order.get(order.indexOf(aComponent)+1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container aContainer, Component aComponent) {
            return order.get(order.indexOf(aComponent)-1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return order.get(1);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return order.lastElement();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container aContainer) {
            return order.get(0);
        }
    }
```

Also, these JTables are being instantiated somewhere else and I have overridden Tab key binding to focus on next component when on last cell. I have made it so as to give me utility on other screens as well.

```
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
            Object actionKey = copyWorkerTable.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).get(keyStroke );
            final Action action= table.getActionMap().get(actionKey);
            Action wrapper = new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if(table.getSelectedRow() >= table.getRowCount()-1 && table.getSelectedColumn() >= table.getColumnCount()-1) {                      
                        if(!table.isCellEditable(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn())){
                            table.transferFocus();
                        }else{
                            table.getCellEditor(table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()).stopCellEditing();
                            table.transferFocus();
                        }

                    }else{
                        action.actionPerformed(e);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right why don't you just use something like this inside you action handler to navigate between tabs ?

```
if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == (tabbedPane.getComponentCount() - 1))
    {

        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(0);

    } else
    {

        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() + 1);

    }
```